# Angular ngRoute not working properly

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a Angular route example but for some reason it's not working.

I've tried many pages and many things but doesn't seem to help.

Here's an

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("Main", ["ngRoute"]);

        app.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
            when("/first", {
                templateUrl: "_Pages/test.html",
                controller: "first"
            }).
            when("/second", {
                templateUrl: "_Pages/index.html",
                controller: "second"
            });
        }]);

        app.controller("first", function ($scope) {
            $scope.list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        });

        app.controller("second", function ($scope) {
            $scope.list = [1, 2, 3];
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="Main">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#/first"> first partial </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#/second"> second partial </a> </li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any advice would be pleasant!

Comment: you got any error on console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that there is a version issue in your angular js file inclusion.

Either you replace your file inclusion code by,

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>    
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

(or)

Copy the entire code from here. Here's the working version of angular JS & Route.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/WADctNCQEgggkZpTAn5V?p=preview)

**Note** : I changed `templateUrl` to `template` for demo purpose.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I managed to incorperate the correct scripts so I could delete the http part.

Answer (score 3):

it seems to be working fine. And Please check the angular version is compatible with the route. i create a sample [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6UN0H4WVVM90Xzg1zpxc?p=preview)

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.5.10" data-semver="1.5.10" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular-router@1.2.0-rc1" data-semver="1.2.0-rc1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Comment: just wondering then, if i would deploy it wouldn't I want to include the correct libraries in my project? How can i make sure that the correct versions are included? should i include version 1.5.10 and version 1.2.0 rc1 into my project using nuget?

Comment: I already got it working with some versions using 1.4.8 and 1.2.16. Upgrading to lastest versions of angular gives me problems not solved by the next comment .

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Angular 1.6, it's probably to do with the changes made to the default hash prefix. That is that as from v1.6.0 upwards `!` is the default hash prefix, whereas it used to be `""` (empty string).

To fix this issue, either...

**Change your links as follows:**

```
<li> <a href="#!/first"> first partial </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#!/second"> second partial </a> </li>
```

Or

**Remove the hash prefix** by injecting `$locationProvider` into the app.config and setting the hash prefix to the empty string as follows:

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

       // with this the links can remain: href="#/first" and href="#/second" 
       $locationProvider.hashPrefix(""); 

       $routeProvider.
            when("/first", {
                templateUrl: "_Pages/test.html",
                controller: "first"
            }).
            when("/second", {
                templateUrl: "_Pages/index.html",
                controller: "second"
            });
   }]);
```

**Further Reading:**

[Angular Issues - Angular 1.6.0 incorrectly redirects to hashbang](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15496)

[Angular Docs - Migrating from v1.5 to 1.6](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-5-to-1-6)